# Can I use stack overflow for fixing problems

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, trademark

As I developer Can I use or (refer) stack overflow for fixing my problem . If I use stack overflow for getting solution is there any issue on copyright

Also learn solution from stack overflow is legal. Can I use that code on my job projects

Comment: Why is this tagged "illegal-immigration"?

Comment: [What is the license for the content I post?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing)

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking its not a problem. If you look at the bottom of this page you will see a note saying "user contributions licensed under [CC BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)". So that's your permission to copy information from this site.

Whether what you are doing is "copying" from a copyright POV is a bit more complex. As a rough rule of thumb:

- You can learn anything and use it, just like a text book. If someone suggests a way to solve a problem you can apply that in your code without any copyright issues. This includes the general principle behind some code, as long as you don't copy the actual code.
- If you copy a block of code from here into your project then you must comply with the copyright license, as set out in the link above and provide appropriate attribution. A link to the answer would be fine, and its good practice to add as a comment to your code anyway, so that your successors can find the information you used.
- However if the code is so simple that there are only a very few ways to do it then there is no creative input in the code and it isn't covered by copyright. So you can just copy it.